# Solving set partition in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve set partition problem in prolog. Suppose, set S = {1,3,4,2,5}. Now to partition it such that

```
L U R = S && L^R = empty
```

I want to Implement a predicate `partition/3` such that `?- partition(S,L,R)` succeeds iff L and R are a valid partition of S . For example, `partition([1,2,3],L,R)` should succeed with answer sub-stitution `L = [1,2], R = [3]` . I don't want to consider duplicate entries for this problem.

Comment: Is this constraint missing in your problem statement ? sum(L) = sum(R)

Comment: Also, what would be duplicate entries for this problem ?. In your example S=[1,2,3], are these valid solutions: L=[1,2], R=[3] ; L=[3], R=[1,2] ; L=[1], R=[2,3], etc ?

Comment: Please explain the meaning of *"I don't want to consider duplicate entries for this problem."* Does that mean that `partition/3` needs to enforce that all lists involved do not contain any duplicates? Or does it rather mean that `partition/3` may (tacitly) assume that all lists (it will ever see) contain no duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem does not require that *sum(L) = sum(R)* as usually stated for the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), then

```
partition(S, [ItemL|L], [ItemR|R]):-
  partition1(S, [ItemL|L], [ItemR|R]).

partition1([], [], []).
partition1([Item|S], [Item|L], R):-
  partition1(S, L, R).
partition1([Item|S], L, [Item|R]):-
  partition1(S, L, R).
```

If the constraint *sum(L) = sum(R)* holds, this change to partition/3 would work (though quite inefficient):

```
partition(S, [ItemL|L], [ItemR|R]):-
  partition1(S, [ItemL|L], [ItemR|R]),
  sumlist([ItemL|L], Sum),
  sumlist([ItemR|R], Sum).
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this! I was getting tripped up by the non-empty requirement, but introducing a subordinate predicate makes it very easy indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case use for [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3)  predicate, we just need to shift the argument.

```
?- append(R, L, [1,2,3]).
L = [1, 2, 3],
R = [];
L = [2, 3],
R = [1];
L = [3],
R = [1, 2];
L = [],
R = [1, 2, 3];
false
```

This will find all possible ordered partitions of the list, now you need to verify the sum of their members.

Now your predicate `partition/3` should be like this:

```
sumList([], 0).
sumList([Head|Tail], S):- number(Head), sumList(Tail, S1), S is S1 + Head.

partition(L1, L, R):- append(L, R, L1), sumList(L, S), sumList(R, S).
```

Test:

```
?- partition([1,2,3], L, R).
L = [1, 2],
R = [3]
```

The problem with this answer is that only the ordered partition will be find

Comment: What about `L=[1,3], R=[2]`?

Comment: Should order be considered or not?

Comment: He doesn't want to see `L=[1,2], R=[3]` *and* `L=[2,1], R=[3]` in the result set because those lists represent the same sets, so they're a duplicate solution. But `L=[1,3], R=[2]` is a valid distinct partition that your solution does not generate.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to solve the partition problem in which sum(L) = sum(R), and L U R = S and L^R = empty

Comment: @gusbro I don't see any mention of summation in the question at all.

Comment: No, but google "Partition problem". Otherwise the solution is trivial

Comment: @gusbro write your own answer, let the OP decide. And try it... it's not as trivial as it sounds.

Comment: @lurker, exactly, partitions of the list are only considered keeping the order of its elements. That's why my answer is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry I missed Daniel's prior comment and your response on that. It's unclear from the OP whether order is to be considered.

Comment: @lurker, my bad, I should research first for the "Partition Problem" :)